# Angular 1.4 - get parent controller property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="order-table-page" ng-controller="SummaryController as summaryCtrl">
   <h3>Summary</h3>
   <!-- Statutes summary information -->
   ...

   <!--List of orders with selected statuses-->
   <div ng-controller="OrderTableController as orderTableCtrl">
    ...
   </div>

</div>
```

So, OrderTableController is a child of SummaryController. Now, in child controller I want to get access to the parent property. In parent class I define:

```
orderApp.controller('SummaryController', ['$location', 'ordersApi', function($location, ordersApi){

    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.summary = [];
    ctrl.test = 'test';

    ...

}]);
```

And in child controller I try to get "test" property:

```
   orderApp.controller('OrderTableController', ['$location', '$scope', 'ordersApi', function($location, $scope, ordersApi){

    var table = this;
    table.orders = [];


    console.log("Table orders 1");
    console.log($scope.$parent.test);

    ...

}]);
```

I expect that $scope.$parent will contain SummaryController scope. But I'm not sure what it contains, because `$scope.$parent.test` is undefined and $scope.$parent has property named summaryCtrl.

My question is how to get parents property "test" form OrderTableController?

Comment: Have you tried $scope.$parent.summaryCtrl.test?

Comment: @SergioFandino yes I tried, and it's working. But I don't understand why $scope.$parent.test doesn't. It looks like something is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your are using `Controller As` feature, it creates a property inside the `$scope` which will represent the controller itself.

So, in your `SummaryController` you have a `test` property. And in scope of this `SummaryController` it will be like `$scope.summaryCtrl.test` - because you defined it as `SummaryController as summaryCtrl`.

Therefore, you need to go in the same path from you child controller to get `test` property (it will be more elegant than working with `$scope.$parent`).

If you need to share some data between controllers, you can try to use shared services (as they are singletons) and use them in related controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to add a refference in `OrderTableController` of `SummaryController` and you'll get everything from `SummaryController` in `OrderTableController` :)

Using `$scope.$parent` is not very elegant. Not neccesary wrong, but not elegant.

Comment: What do you mean by reference to controller? Could you include sample code?

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have a proper example right now, but tomorrow I will add here a comment with example, ok?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you are using `this` instead of `$scope` in the parent controller, if you do `$scope.test='test'` you could get it in the way you want `$scope.$parent.test`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f2zyvf17/

PD: You can see the difference of using $scope or this in this question:
['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)